# How to keep a variable in a string from changing python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I'm new to python and I've got an assignment to Write a program that inputs a string from the user and than to print the string in which all instances of the first character have been replaced by an 'e' except for the first character itself.
This is what I got so far:

```
sent = input('Please enter a string: ')
var1 = sent[0]
var2 = 'e'
mod_sent = sent.replace(var1,var2)
print(mod_sent)
```

I know that nothing there is supposed to keep the first character from changing but I feel like I have tried everything and just have to delete because it is not working.
Would like an explanation and just an answer if possible please.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the first character is changing in the `sent.replace` you called, because python replaces *every* character in the string with the substitute.

You can just revert the first character, which should be easy since you stored it in `var1` (try using more descriptive names next time).

```
mod_sent = var1 + mod_sent[1:]
```

Add this before your print statement and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string `str[1:]` will return the whole string except first character:

```
sent = input('Please enter a string: ')
var1 = sent[0]
var2 = 'e'
mod_sent = var1 + sent[1:].replace(var1,var2)
print(mod_sent)
```